# Github Windows breaking repository - How do I clear my whole repository?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm fairly new to Git and ran into some very strange issues using Github.
I have a repository on github where I want to push my changes in from Windows (using the github for windows client). All goes well, but when I try to pull the changes on my VPS, I get the following output:

```
remote: Counting objects: 278, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (121/121), done.
remote: Total 278 (delta 128), reused 271 (delta 121)
Receiving objects: 100% (278/278), 7.56 MiB | 3.05 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (128/128), done.
error: refs/remotes/origin/master does not point to a valid object!
error: Trying to write ref refs/heads/master with nonexistant object 38386ca31ffd0ba741e05ad9bd663b4bc6c1fa86
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'HEAD'.
```

I've tried to delete every file in the repository, then commit and force a push to "start clean", but this doesn't work either. I don't want to simply create a new repository because I have several people following my project.

If I do a force push from my VPS (so it reverts the commits I made in Windows) everything works fine again, but when I try to then push in Windows again, I get rejected/fast-forward errors.

I made a local backup of my project files, so I can try to get a 'clean' branch again without having to worry about losing my files.

So, my question is: How do I get rid of every single commit in my repository to start clean?

Comment: Have you tried cloning the repository again on both systems? Maybe the problem is in your local repositories.

Comment: Tried that. Creating a new clone gives the error as shown in the first post. I _have_ to force a push on the original clone to revert the last commits, otherwise the branch stays broken forever.

Answer (score 0):

run msysgit from the command line on your windows machine instead of using the github application. There do a `git fsck` to see if you have any corrupt objects.